# Why does the main window in Qt disappear?

Tags: qt

Create a simple Qt4 Gui Application, surround the window construction and show commands in an if statement and run the application.
When I do this the window flashes for a microsecond and then disappears ... Why?
I'm running Qt Creator 1.2.1, Based on Qt 4.5.2 (32 bit), on Windows 7 Pro.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    bool taut = true;
    if ( taut) {
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scope of `w` is within the if statement. The variable is not defined anymore after you leave the last `}`.

I think this is why the window disappears.